# Combine 2 SQL Queries into 1 Using results from the First

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to SQL and PLSQL. I'm thinking there is a way to join these two queries, but I'm stumped. They are exactly the same, except the first query finds a distinct e.identifying_party, say "5111", then the second one finds a distinct child_id using e.identifying_party = "5111".

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.identifying_party
FROM voucher b,
  cc_authorization d,
  case e,
      episode g,
      invoice c,
      invoice_item f,
      svcperiod_info v
    WHERE b.cc_authorization_id = d.cc_authorization_id
    AND d.subsidy_id            = g.episode_id
    AND g.case_id               = e.case_id
    AND b.voucher_id            = f.voucher_id
    AND f.invoice_id            = c.invoice_id
    AND v.svcperiod_id          = c.svcperiod_id
    AND f.status                = 8
    AND f.net_amount            > 0
    AND (v.end_dt              >= '01-APR-17'
    AND v.end_dt                < '02-APR-17')
    AND e.case_id               <4000;
```

The second query is exactly the same, but uses an input for e.identifying_party :

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.child_id
FROM voucher b,
  cc_authorization d,
  case e,
      episode g,
      invoice c,
      invoice_item f,
      svcperiod_info v
    WHERE b.cc_authorization_id = d.cc_authorization_id
    AND d.subsidy_id            = g.episode_id
    AND g.case_id               = e.case_id
    AND b.voucher_id            = f.voucher_id
    AND f.invoice_id            = c.invoice_id
    AND v.svcperiod_id          = c.svcperiod_id
    AND f.status                = 8
    AND f.net_amount            > 0
    AND (v.end_dt              >= '01-APR-17'
    AND v.end_dt                < '02-APR-17')
    AND e.identifying_party     = 5111
    AND e.case_id               <4000;
```

Also, I am debugging someone else's code, so if there are any other edits or missing information, please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `from` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `join` syntax.

Comment: You should no longer used this join syntax of the 1980s. Explicit joins were introduced in 1992 for a reason. Don't compare dates with strings. Especially not with ones containing date names in some language you hope the DBMS to understand and interpret correctly. Use date literals instaead: `AND (v.end_dt >= DATE '2017-04-01' AND v.end_dt < '2017-04-02'`. Don't use obfuscating alias names. What has the letter `c` to do with invoices? Use `i` or `inv` or something else we can read and understand.

Comment: what did you mean join? how would you like your result be? if you use Select distinct e.identifying_party, b.child_id on your first query, you will also get the child_id which has identifying_party = 5111 which is a condition on your second query.

Comment: Hi ! Just wanted to say that I noticed you have a table named "case" and that is a reserved word in SQL (at least Oracle and Mssql). This could lead to unpredictable behavior and is better avoided.

Comment: In my last comment the keyword `DATE` is missing in front of the second date literal. Sorry.

Comment: The first query doesn't find *a* distinct `e.identifying_party`, but a list of such. So the first query might return 5111, 5112, and 5113. And what exactly is the second query to do with these three numbers then?

Comment: Thank you for the edits @ThorstenKettner !

Comment: @Dessma Unfortunately we can't change that Table name...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the queries are identical except for the particular field you're pulling out, then logically the query returns all the data you need - you just need to ask for it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.identifying_party, b.child_id
  FROM voucher b
  INNER JOIN cc_authorization d
    ON d.cc_authorization_id = b.cc_authorization_id
  INNER JOIN episode g
    ON g.subsidy_id = d.episode_id
  INNER JOIN case e
    ON e.case_id = g.case_id
  INNER JOIN invoice_item f
    ON f.voucher_id = b.voucher_id
  INNER JOIN invoice c
    ON c.invoice_id = f.invoice_id
  INNER JOIN svcperiod_info v
    ON v.svcperiod_id = c.svcperiod_id
  WHERE f.status     = 8 AND
        f.net_amount > 0 AND
        v.end_dt    >= '01-APR-17' AND
        v.end_dt    <  '02-APR-17' AND
        e.case_id   <  4000
  ORDER BY IDENTIFYING_PARTY, CHILD_ID
```

Here I rewrote the query to use "modern" joins (SQL-92 - 25 years "new" - my, how time does fly :-) but the original query should work just fine.

This will give you the distinct combinations of IDENTIFYING_PARTY and CHILD_ID. I added an ORDER BY to ensure that the results are returned in some reasonable order.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

The one way of joining is:

```
Select distinct b.child_id         
        From voucher b, cc_authorization d, case e, episode g, invoice c, invoice_item f, svcperiod_info v        
        Where b.cc_authorization_id = d.cc_authorization_id  and d.subsidy_id = g.episode_id and g.case_id = e.case_id       
        and b.voucher_id = f.voucher_id and f.invoice_id = c.invoice_id and v.svcperiod_id = c.svcperiod_id
        and f.status = 8 and  f.net_amount > 0 and (v.end_dt >= '01-APR-17' and v.end_dt < '02-APR-17') and e.case_id<4000 and e.identifying_party in (Select distinct e1.identifying_party         
            From voucher b, cc_authorization d, case e1, episode g, invoice c, invoice_item f, svcperiod_info v        
            Where b.cc_authorization_id = d.cc_authorization_id  and d.subsidy_id = g.episode_id and g.case_id = e1.case_id       
            and b.voucher_id = f.voucher_id and f.invoice_id = c.invoice_id and v.svcperiod_id = c.svcperiod_id
            and f.status = 8 and  f.net_amount > 0 and (v.end_dt >= '01-APR-17' and v.end_dt < '02-APR-17') and e1.case_id<4000);
```

Notice that I have used `e1` alias in sub-query for the table `case`. You may need to use different alias for other tables in sub=query.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I guess I was hoping for a more concise way, but maybe this is the only way!

Comment: Some optimization can be done but I think one need to know more details of tables and relationships.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured as well...They are just too large and complex at the moment for a simple paragraph of info. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the suggestions of others and what you've said about the queries, this could work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT v.child_id
FROM voucher v
INNER JOIN cc_authorization cca ON v.cc_authorization_id = cca.cc_authorization_id
INNER JOIN episode ep cca.subsidy_id = ep.episode_id
INNER JOIN case ca ON ep.case_id = ca.case_id
INNER JOIN invoice_item it ON d.voucher_id = it.voucher_id
INNER JOIN invoice inv ON it.invoice_id = inv.invoice_id
INNER JOIN svcperiod_info spi ON inv.svcperiod_id = spi.svcperdiod_id
WHERE it.status = 8
AND it.net_amount > 0
AND (spi.end_dt >= DATE'01-APR-17' AND spi.end_dt < DATE'02-APR-17')
AND ca.case_id < 4000
AND ca.identifying_party IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT ca1.identifying_party
  FROM voucher v
  INNER JOIN cc_authorization cca ON v.cc_authorization_id = cca.cc_authorization_id
  INNER JOIN episode ep cca.subsidy_id = ep.episode_id
  INNER JOIN case ca1 ON ep.case_id = ca.case_id
  INNER JOIN invoice_item it ON d.voucher_id = it.voucher_id
  INNER JOIN invoice inv ON it.invoice_id = inv.invoice_id
  INNER JOIN svcperiod_info spi ON inv.svcperiod_id = spi.svcperdiod_id
  WHERE it.status = 8
  AND it.net_amount > 0
  AND (spi.end_dt >= DATE'01-APR-17' AND spi.end_dt < DATE'02-APR-17')
  AND ca.case_id < 4000
);
```

Notice how I have changed the joins to use ANSI-standard joins and given each table a more appropriate alias.

However, I think it could be improved, if you can provide more info about the data. Why do we need to run the same logic in both the inner and outer query? Could they be combined into the same query (e.g. SELECT DISTINCT v.child_id, ca1.identifying_party...)?

Comment: What the original writer was doing is creating a list from the first querie, and then looping through the second querie pulling one value from that created list (ca.identifying_party)